# How to extract few hex numbers from a line?

Tags: regex, sed

I have a file containing these lines

```
Entry :  12300000
F Blocks:   0x00000020 0x00000000 0x000a1b00
S Blocks:   0x00100000 0x0000001c 0x00000150
```

I would like to extract only the numbers associated to the line starting with `F Blocks` as string.

Line can be easily extracted using :

```
sed -n '/F Blocks:/p' filename
```

However, I am still extract line numbers and check format using regex

```
blocks="$(sed -n 's/F Blocks:[\t ]\+\([0-9a-f]\+\)[ ]\+\([0-9a-f]\+\)[ ]\+\([0-9a-f]\+\)/0x\1 0x\2 0x\3/p' filename)"
```

What's going wrong with the given regex ?

EDIT1: Update `F Blocks..` line.

Comment: did you mean to match optional 0x in front of the numbers? `F Blocks:[\t ]+(0x)?([0-9a-f]+)[ ]+(0x)?([0-9a-f]+)[ ]+(0x)?([0-9a-f]+)` https://regex101.com/r/bNa6A1/1 and replace with `0x\2 0x\4 0x\6`

Comment: @ogs : You are searching for strings of hexadecimal digits, separated by spaces, but your input data contains hexadecimal digits **and the letter x**. Hance you don't get a match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can optionally match the `(0x)?` before the number using `sed -E` and the replacement groups will be `0x\2 0x\4 0x\6/`

```
blocks="$(sed -nE 's/F Blocks:[\t ]+(0x)?([0-9a-f]+)[ ]+(0x)?([0-9a-f]+)[ ]+(0x)?([0-9a-f]+)/0x\2 0x\4 0x\6/p' filename)"
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bNa6A1/1/) | [Bash demo](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/P8Q1IsRWRSM5sUTBxkbX1c@FyzWvpKhSwUpBwdDI2AAEuNwUnHLyk7OLgWIKBhVgMQMjAzjTAMpMNEwCKg5GU2yIpAIIDJNhTENTAy6QfZpcXFxJYC22SioaxakpCrp5rgrqxfpwa6NjShRitTUMKjTtNaINdC0TddNitTWjiRTTN6iIMQJaGmMCIsz0C9SBPrVRAXlcU4krNTkjX0EFYv///wA)

The replacement will look like:

```
0x00000020 0x00000000 0x000a1b00
```

Comment: Thanks for the advices and the specifics links ! Very nice tools

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as well :

```
grep '^F' input.txt | awk -F':' '
{split($2,numbers, " "); 
  for(ix in numbers) { 
     if(numbers[ix] ~ /0x[0-9]+/){  
         printf("%s ",numbers[ix]) 
     }
  }
}'
```

And it will print :

```
0x00000000 0x000a1b00
```

Regards!